# How to manage communication between to independent react components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, redux, reactjs-flux

I would like to implement a web application similar to messenger.com, also based on react framework. My problem is to manage the communication between List and Content components, as they're unrelated to each other. The render method of their parent component looks like this:

return (
"<" List "/>"
"<"Content "/>"
)

I want content component to refresh and load some data depending on selected list element, similar to messenger.com. [Here's  simple mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6fzq.png)

I've read a lot about redux, but I simply can't imaging how it should be implemented in this situation.

Here's also my whole react script running on the browser side: http://pastebin.com/ua928BEc

Sorry guys if it's a noob question I'm just starting with react :)

Many thanks for reading this,

Wojtek

Comment: you're still in plain old JS land. Just use event handling. If some part of your UI generates events that another completely unrelated part needs to act on, literally dispatch events and have the relevant components listen in (register listeners with componentWillMount, and unregister during componentWillUnmount)

Comment: Or wrap both components with a component that manages the event handling, as it knows both children

Comment: @larrydahooster That's already the case. The main component Messenger renders ThreadsList and Thread components, which are equivalents for List and Content on the mockup picture :) The problem is, that the particular list element has to be chosen deeper in hierarchy so I had to forward it's state through the whole components tree and back. I hope there's a better way to solve this problem.

Comment: @wklm I don't see why both components should handle a communication directly or propagate that deeper. I think you just need to call an action that will change an store with the content you need for that list.

Comment: @juangarcia Yeah, this is exactly the way I wanted to do it. I Have defined a global variable where I store an ID of the current thread.

My render method of ThreadsList looks like this: http://pastebin.com/EzEiUbpb

The problem is, already by rendering all the buttons seem to be "clicked" so i got all of possible thread IDs in console output already in render time. Next the application doesn't really react on clicking. So I thought that I need to store it as components state and forward it through the whole tree to main component in order to make it works.

Comment: @wklm here is an approach with flux that could be of you interest

https://github.com/facebook/flux/tree/master/examples/flux-chat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Thinking in React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html) is a great tutorial explaining state ownership in React and how components communicate. Once you get comfortable with it, you can try to implement this in vanilla React.

When you are comfortable in React but notice that some of your components get bloated because of all the state handling logic, you might want to check out a Flux implementation like Redux to offload the state handling to it. [Getting Started with Redux](https://egghead.io/series/getting-started-with-redux) is a set of free introductory videos to using Redux with React, and they are complemented well by the official [basics tutorial](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/).

But [don’t rush into Flux or Redux until you understand React](https://github.com/petehunt/react-howto).

Comment: thanks Dan, I've solved it after reading thinking in react :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this problem with a flux architecture.

Since you are working with a list and a content, then the selection of the list item you have, would call an action (get content of this list), that action would be dispatched, and would give the store the values you need in the content.

If you need further communication between components you can give some props to list / content components.

[flux architecture description.](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html)

[Flux example chat and others examples.](https://github.com/facebook/flux/tree/master/examples/flux-chat)

Answer (score 0):

If the system is simple use a global messaging system such as pub/sub or signals: PubSubJS , https://github.com/Hypercubed/mini-signals , http://ctheu.com/2015/02/12/how-to-communicate-between-react-components/

If your application is more complex look into using a flux implementation (flux, redux...). You connect your UI components to flux store(s). You update the state in the store and the components will automatically re-render.